# How do I check if breakpoints are hit in a certain order?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to set up a GDB script that sets some breakpoints and makes sure that they are hit in a certain order, and if not throw an error.

It would look something like:

```
break *0x400de0    # Should be hit first
break *0x40f650    # Should be hit second
break *0x40f662    # Should be hit third
run
# hits breakpoint #
if (??? == "0x400de0")
   continue
   # hits breakpoint #
   if (??? == "0x40f650")
      continue
      # hits breakpoint #
      if (??? == "0x40f662")
          print "The correct thing happened!"
          # Do some things here....
          quit
      else
          print "ERROR"
          quit
    else
      print "ERROR"
      quit
else
    print "ERROR"
    quit
```

However, I'm somewhat stuck on getting the address at the breakpoint into a variable. I've looked into using `frame` which prints the current address, however I have no idea how to get that into a variable for comparison.

I've looked into using Python-GDB scripts to do this, however, it seems a little complicated for my application. I will use it if it is the only option however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a state machine.

```
set $state = 0
break *0x400de0
commands
  if $state == 0
    set $state = 1
  else
    printf "error, state is %d expected 0\n", $state
  end
end
break *0x40f650
commands
  if $state == 1
    set $state = 2
  else
    printf "error, state is %d expected 1\n", $state
  end
end
break *0x40f662
commands
  if $state == 2
    printf "done\n"
  else
    printf "error, state is %d expected 2\n", $state
  end
end

run
```

Comment: Ah, a state machine, of course! This is exactly what I needed, thank you!